# Is there a comparison key for set objects?

Tags: python

Is there a way to give a comparator to `set()` so when adding items it checks an attribute of that item for likeness rather than if the item is the same? For example, I want to use objects in a set that can contain the same value for one attribute.

```
class TestObj(object):
    def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value = value 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

values = set()
a = TestObj('a')
b = TestObj('b')
a2 = TestObj('a')
values.add(a) # Ok
values.add(b) # Ok
values.add(a2) # Not ok but still gets added

# Hypothetical code
values = set(lambda x, y: x.value != y.value)
values.add(a) # Ok
values.add(b) # Ok
values.add(a2) # Not added
```

I have implemented my own sorta thing that does similar functionality but wanted to know if there was a builtin way.

```
from Queue import Queue
class UniqueByAttrQueue(Queue):
    def __init__(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        Queue.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.attr = attr

    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self.queue = set()

    def _put(self, item):
        # Potential race condition, worst case message gets put in twice
        if hasattr(item, self.attr) and item not in self:
            self.queue.add(item)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        item_attr = getattr(item, self.attr)
        for x in self.queue:
            x_attr = getattr(x, self.attr)
            if x_attr == item_attr:
                return True
        return False

    def _get(self):
        return self.queue.pop()
```

Comment: Set and dict equality is determined by the object hash, so you could override the `__hash__` method to be based on the `value` attribute.

Comment: I'd think that set would take care of that for you. It will only reject identical objects, not objects that are partially different.

Comment: Well that is the problem exactly @roadrunner66. I want it to reject partially the same hence why I want to give it a comparison key.

Comment: @tzaman: Object hash *and* normal equality, so you also have to implement `__eq__`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) on the object in terms of the attribute in question and it will work with `set`s. For example:

```
class TestObj(object):
    def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value = value 
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not instance(other, TestObj):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.value == other.value

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)
```

If you can't change the object (or don't want to, say, because other things are important to equality), then use a `dict` instead. You can either do:

```
mydict[obj.value] = obj
```

so new objects replace old, or

```
mydict.setdefault(obj.value, obj)
```

so old objects are maintained if the `value` in question is already in the keys. Just make sure to iterate using `.viewvalues()` (Python 2) or `.values()` (Python 3) instead of iterating directly (which would get the keys, not the values). You could actually use this approach to make a custom `set`-like object with a key as you describe (though you'd need to implement many more methods than I show to make it efficient, the default methods are usually fairly slow):

```
from collections.abc import MutableSet  # On Py2, collections without .abc

class keyedset(MutableSet):
    def __init__(self, it=(), key=lambda x: x):
        self.key = key
        self.contents = {}
        for x in it:
            self.add(x)

    def __contains__(self, x):
        # Use anonymous object() as default so all arguments handled properly
        sentinel = object()
        getval = self.contents.get(self.key(x), sentinel)
        return getval is not sentinel and getval == x

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.contents.values())  # itervalues or viewvalues on Py2

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.contents)

    def add(self, x):
        self.contents.setdefault(self.key(x), x)

    def discard(self, x):
        self.contents.pop(self.key(x), None)
```

Comment: That's a weird downvote. The only problem I see here is that you assume `other` is a `TestObj` instance in `__eq__` instead of checking and returning `NotImplemented`. Other than that, this is a great answer.

Comment: @user2357112: Yeah, I was trying to keep it short (because I was planning to add the simple `keyedset` implementation, and it would get long enough). :-)

Comment: @user2357112 As an aside, I think that `NotImplemented` is used for abstract-style classes (where the idea is to subclass them and define your own method). Generally you use `TypeError` or one of its subclasses if an operation isn't defined for a given type.

Comment: @Paul: You'd use `NotImplemented` in this case actually, because it tells Python that you don't know how to handle the comparison, but allows it to try using the `__eq__` of the other object to see if it supports it. If the right side object knows how to compare to the left, the left _must_ return `NotImplemented` so Python will know to try the right.

Comment: @Paul: No, `NotImplemented` is there to let the other guy define an equality operation. For example, NumPy arrays can be `==`ed with just about anything.

Comment: @Paul: Even types like `bool`, which can't be subclassed at all, return `NotImplemented` instead of raising an error for unsupported operators.

Comment: Good to know! Glad I said something!

Comment: @user2357112: It's even more complicated than that. For subclasses with disparate comparator functions, Python will call the overload for the child class first rather than the parent (even if the child is on the right), since the child is likely to have the context for the comparison the parent lacks. It's when there is no inheritance relationship like that that `NotImplemented` is really important, for example, my `keyedset` is not a subclass of `set`, so if `set` didn't return `NotImplemented` when it couldn't compare to a `keyedset`, `keyedset` wouldn't have a chance to do the check itself.